# How to submit clone of jQuery form with current data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to dynamically create and submit HTML form.

I join many forms into one AJAX request so I clone them and send by jQuery. Code in the link shows the not working part. The problem is that jQuery is sending original HTML code instead of generated/user changes code.

What do I wrong?
http://ajax.dev.brown.sk/test1.html

Whole example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function(){

                // copy inputs and take it to form element
                $clone = $(this).clone(true,true);

                // display the code to below
                $("pre:first").text($clone[0].outerHTML);


                // ajax form submit
                $.post("/post.php", $clone.serialize(), function(data){
                    // data contains output of <?php print_r($_POST) ?>
                    $("pre:last").text(data);
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form>
            <select name="select">
                <option value="a">aaa</option>
                <option value="b" selected="selected">bbb</option>
                <option value="c">ccc</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

        <hr />
        <pre></pre>

        <hr />
        <pre></pre>

    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I think the problem is with serialization of cloned form. Check this example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function(){

                // copy inputs and take it to form element
                $clone = $(this).clone();

                // display the serialized values below
                $("pre").text($clone.serialize());

                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form>
            <select name="select">
                <option value="a">aaa</option>
                <option value="b" selected="selected">bbb</option>
                <option value="c">ccc</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

        <pre></pre>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add some code here to help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it response to the **delegate** since it not with the **initial DOM**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").on('submit',function(){

                // copy inputs and take it to form element
                $clone = $(this).clone(true,true);

                // display the code to below
                $("pre:first").append($clone[0].outerHTML);


                // ajax form submit
                $.post("/post.php", $clone.serialize(), function(data){
                    $("pre:last").append(data);
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
```

**Edit**

You are only getting the outerHTML and you need everything

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").on('submit',function(){

                // copy inputs and take it to form element
                $clone = $(this).clone(true,true);

                // display the code to below
                $("pre:first").append($clone);


                // ajax form submit
                $.post("/post.php", $clone.serialize(), function(data){
                    $("pre:last").append(data);
                });

                return false;
            });
        });
```

I hope this can help :)

Comment: I change it and it didn't help :(

Comment: Why to use method "append" instead of "text"? The 2 <PRE>'s are just for debug (result checking) there.

Comment: but you are reseting the text with the new one

Comment: I couldnt add my commend to the comment. Please check my edit.